# Right way to export\transfer WildFly 9 server options to other PC

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

I need to export\transfer options (such as DataSource to MySQL) to other PC\server. How to do it correctly?

I had tried to copy and rename standalone.xml and run it on other PC by following command:

```
./standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-(full)-myProject.xml
```

Is it right way?

And next problem - how export installed module (in WildFly) for MySQL correctly?
I installed it like this (as module) at my machine http://hpehl.info/jdbc-driver-setup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly encourage you to use the jboss-cli to run this instead.  Copying the files will work but I would argue that it's better to have a repeatable process.

To add a datasource, you'd run the following.  Since you're using WildFly 9, it can be a bit simpler.  Put the following commands in a file - for example, db_setup.txt.  Then run `$WILDFLY_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=db_setup.txt`.  The file will contain something like the following:

```
embed-server --std-out=echo --server-config=standalone.xml

batch

module add --name=com.mysql.driver --resources=/path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=mysql:add(driver-name="mysql",driver-module-name="com.mysql.driver",driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=myPool/:add(connection-url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbName,driver-name=mysql,jndi-name=java:/jdbc/dbName,password=password,user-name=user)
```

**WARNING** - I have not fully tested these commands so they may require a bit of tweaking.  But the concepts are there.

The one issue you'll have is that, during testing, the jboss-cli.sh command will just exit if there is an error.  You may want a file to remove these too:

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=myPool/:remove
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=my:remove
module remove --name=com.mysql.driver
```

Comment: I type `jboss-cli.bat --file=db_setup.txt` on Windows and nothings happens. The file is still empty. The text in command line: "Press any key to continue...". I don't know where my error.

P.S. I  set env variable PATH to wildfly-9.0.2.Final\bin and also created db_setup.txt in necessary folder.

Comment: I have standalone.xml in the posting and it looks like you're using something else.  Try renaming the file that I show in the example.

Comment: If you don't have `connect` as the first line in the script you need to add `-c`. So `jboss-cli.bat -c --file=db_setup.txt`.

Comment: With "-c" argument all the same. Also I have tried to indicate other file name. And was: " this file not found". So I created it on appropriate dir and this exception 'll no more. Only silent and "press any key to continue".

Comment: Also question: how load config from it file?

Comment: stdunbar, well this command `$WILDFLY_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=db_setup.txt` will run script. But how can I automatically write out my WildFly's configuration to such script file?

Comment: @wikk - therein lies the problem with doing the configuration without a repeatable process - there isn't an easy way to dump the current configuration.  [this article](http://wildfly.org/news/2015/03/13/Offline-CLI/) has a link to [this file](https://developer.jboss.org/servlet/JiveServlet/download/53050-3-129627/embedded-server.txt.zip) that will recreate standalone-full from an empty configuration.  But you'll still have some work to do to trim it down to what you need.