# Class Not Found Exception for com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in Wildfly 10

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, wildfly

I'm using Wildfly 10 and my datasource in the standalone.xml is:

```
        <datasources>
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySQL_AAA" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aaa</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>root</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
```

I'm running this code in my Java bean:

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

and I get this error message:

```
10:29:59,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from [Module "deployment.AAA_5.war:main" from Service Module Loader]


10:29:59,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15) at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
```

I read documentation that said I needed to have the driver in my lib folder but that didn't work.  I'm sure the solution is simple but I don't see it.  Can someone point me in the right direction.  Some documentation that I can use as a resource would be great.

Comment: Have you followed [these docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/DataSource+configuration)?

Comment: Those docs are for Widlfly 8.  I'm using 10.  I have a functioning datasourse in Wildfly.  I'm using it to populate the rest of the app.  It's definition is shown in the first section of my question.  I need to know how to access the driver properly.

Comment: I've used the same script for Wildfly 8, 9, and 10 - there have not been that many changes.  See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459066/right-way-to-export-transfer-wildfly-9-server-options-to-other-pc/37467250#37467250) for a better way overall.  You should never get the driver directly and should be using connection pools.

Comment: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` hasn't been necessary since 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop mysql driver in the `deployments` folder in your wildfly , it will be deployed automatically  , then it will become available.
**EDIT**:
installing mysql JDBC driver in wildfly as deployment will not give you access to mysql classes because of class-loaders behaviors, you can access the database connections through `jndi` datasources only, and you will not need to use `Class.forName()`.

```
InitialContext context=new InitialContext();
DataSource d=(DataSource)context.lookup(yourDataSourceName);
```

However, if you still need to use mysql specific classes  in your project , you have to drop the driver in your `web-project/WEB-INF/lib` folder.(but be careful about this since it will not be related to the deployed driver)

Comment: I already have the driver in the deployments folder in Widlfly.  I also have a datasource configured in the standalone.xml.

Comment: Where do you exactly call the (Class , method):
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: This seems to be the solution to my problem. I used:   InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
   DataSource d = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:/MySqlDS");
 then:   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, d.getConnection());

Comment: Important note, in this way you dont close the connection, which will cause the connection pool to be exhausted.
close  the connection in your finally block.
Good luck

Comment: I ended up using it like this:   InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
   DataSource datasource = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:/MySqlDS");

   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, datasource.getConnection());   Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are most welcome Mindlayr! But this way your application will hang after some reports printing, because you dont close the connections.  You should get the connection in local variable, then close it in the finally statement.

Comment: Good point.  I'll make sure to close the connection.  I'm just writing test code right now but I'll make sure to close it before I put it into production.